# How does a Potion of Giant's Strength affect a wildshaped Druid?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape, potions

What would happen to a Druid's stats if they drank a Potion of Giant's Strength before they wildshaped? What about after they wildshaped?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In both cases, the increase in strength is applied to the creature's strength score.

If they did it before:

> You retain the benefit of any features from your class,
>   race, **or other source** and can use them if the new
>   form is physically capable of doing so. (PHB p.67)

If they did it afterwards, the potion affects the creature normally and as above, would remain in effect when changing back.

Comment: That quote seems like a bad fit, specifically mentioning features. Do you have one that better points to spells specifically being persistent?

Comment: @Weaveworker89 **Feature**, noun, distinctive attribute or aspect of something - in what way is the effect of a potion not an other source feature?

Comment: He may have confused feature with feat.

Answer (score 0):

I would say **No** if you drink the potion as a Druid and then transform because Wild Shape says:

> Your game statistics are replaced by the statistics of the beast, but you retain your alignment, personality, and Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores. (PHB p. 67)

That means *Strength* is not kept. At the same time, the potion effects may be considered a *special feature* as underlined by Dale M.'s answer and in that case the other rule may very well mean that the *Strength* remains the same in this special case.

At the same time, if the new form is rather weak (i.e. a small lizard)

> You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or other source and can use them **if the new form is physically capable of doing so**. (PHB p.67)

its bones could crack before it can use a 20+ strength score, but magic works in strange ways...